# Android and Facebook Contact Picker Issuer

Tags: android, contactscontract

The short version of my question is: How do I access the phone numbers of contacts that were synced from 3rd party apps?

Here is the long version:

I can access the regular Android contacts pretty easily.  The issue is when the only information in the contact list is synced with a 3rd party app like Facebook or LinkedIn.  If I physically went and typed someone's phone number into the Google Contacts List, everything works fine.

However, if this phone number came from syncing my facebook account to my contact list, no phone number shows up, even though if I navigated to Google's pre-made contact list I can see a phone number is actually attached to the contact.  Here is the code I use for getting the phone numbers.

```
public void populateNumberLists(View view)
{
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
    TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.contactEntryText);

    String str = (String) tv.getText();
    Cursor cursor = getNumbers(str);

    String[] fields = new String[] {
            cursor.getColumnName(1).toString()
    };


    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.numberentry, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.numberEntryText});
    mNumberList.setAdapter(adapter);            

}

private Cursor getNumbers(String str)
{

    final Uri URIs = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    final String ID = ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY;
    String id = "";
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cu = cr.query(URIs, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " = '" + str + "'", null, null);

    if (cu.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ID));
    }

    cu.close();

    // Run query
    Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Phone._ID,
            Phone.NUMBER

    };

    String selection = Phone.LOOKUP_KEY + " = '" + id + "' and (" + Phone.TYPE + " = '" + Phone.TYPE_HOME+"' or " + Phone.TYPE + " = '" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE+"' or " + Phone.TYPE + " = '" + Phone.TYPE_WORK+"' or " + Phone.TYPE + " = '" + Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE+"')";

    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";


    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

}
```

Basically, the populateNumberLists function takes a clicked item from a list view, determines which contact from the list was clicked and calls the function getNumbers.

The getNumbers function takes actual name that was clicked, gets the lookup key for that name, then grabs all the phone numbers associated with that lookup key.

Oh, related to this, the only names displayed in the contact list are ones where ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER equals 1.  So I know that all the contacts that can be selected have a phone number attached.

Comment: If you want to display only those contacts that have Google phone numbers see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11726920/813029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is not included in the ContactPicker because Facebook forbid that.
This is a politically thing and won't be solved soon: Google wants Facebook to share data, Facebook uses Google but doesn't share..

Comment: I read that somewhere, so it sounds familiar.  I just didn't know that it applied to my particular scenario.  So, how do I filter out the contacts that fall into this category?  I only briefly mentioned this in my original post, but I use the HAS_PHONE_NUMBER flag to determine if the name should be listed in the contacts in the first place.  This means that a good majority of my facebook contacts should not be listed as a selectable option since the phone number I have came from facebook.  Is there some better way, besides the HAS_PHONE_NUMBER flag?

Comment: wasted an afternoon messing around with contact pickers cos of this!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the [Facebook SDK for android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/FQLQuery.java) to do this. Use an [FQL query to get the phone number](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446).