# Can't fetch phone numbers for linked contacts when one of the groups is invisible

Tags: android

I faced with problem while fetching phone numbers for linked contacts on HTC phone.

The problem only with contacts that have phone numbers in invisible group.

E.g. I have contact in addressbook that linked from Google and Facebook accounts.

```
    Contact1 - Google account (contact name, email)
    Contact1 - Facebook account (contact name, phone number)
```

In the Contacts settings Google group is **active** and Facebook group is **hidden**.

Here what I am doing in the code.

Preparing cursor for ListView that shows only contacts with phone numbers and in visible group.

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
    };
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(AllContactsNewActivity.this,
            uri, projection, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +" = 1 " + 
                    " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'",
                    selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

**The Contact1 is presented in the list.**

When user click on this contact I am fetching phone numbers from selected contact, but get empty list.

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
    AllContactsNewActivity.this,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);
```

I have already tried to use RAW_CONTACT_ID, _ID, LOOKUP_KEY for fetching numbers but w/o luck.

Could some one give me piece of advice how I can fetch phone numbers for these contacts or just not show such contacts in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and searched for hours to find a solution. This is probably too late for you, but if you use the following code the facebook contacts are not included in the listing.

Please note that this uses deprecated code. I suspect, however, that we are stuck using it until facebook gets their act together and stops violating every rule Google ever made regarding contacts.

Calling code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CONTACT);
```

Later in onActivityResult

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));  
    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
    Toast.makeText(this,  name + " has number " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```